# is a possible to integrate other tabs in Kibana like website?

Tags: wordpress, elasticsearch, meteor, tabs, kibana

I want to use Kibana to visualize all values which are stored in Elasticsearch and I want to extend the Kibana Dashboard with other tabs such as reports and others.

Is it possible to do this with Kibana or should I use another platform like meteor or Wordpress to create tabs and implement Kibana in one of the tabs.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `iframe` to embed the exported kibana dashboard on to meteor? If so, then it will hide the left side dashboard of kibana. If you observe the query string of the iframe, you will see `<kibana_host>?embed=true`. Remove the `embed=true` part to enable kibana's sidebar on the embedded page.

Comment: No. Iam using now highchart library by meteor to visualize my data but i want to change from meteor to Kibana because iam using already elasticsearch and it will be easier to do the visualization with Kibana but i want to have also other tabs with other informations on Kibana Dashboard. is it possible to add other tabs where i will click on button to make a report or write comments??

Comment: You can move all the visualizations on to kibana, and still have the meteor app as a shell to host different visualization (and reports) that kibana generates. I don't think,. at the moment you can customize the way kibana is built up.